# subdomain to main domain without changing url with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have "**main_domain.com**" and "**sub.main_domain.com**" and there is a folder inside main_domain called "**sub**".

So if I type sub.main_domain.com I go to main_domain.com/sub/ and it's ok, but I see that url is changing.
Can I prevent change of url?

My code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.main_domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://main_domain.com/sub/
```

Thanks, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting 'Proxy' ("[P]") directive in your RewriteRule. See below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.main_domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://main_domain.com/sub/ [P]
```

Please note that for being able to use the Proxy directive, you need to have 'mod_proxy' and 'mod_proxy_http' enabled in your Apache configuration file.

Let me know if my answer helped you.